# I completely destroyed Unity! Help?

Tags: 11.10, unity

I noticed that the grid plugin wasn't restoring windows to the original size. So I went to ccsm to try to tweak the options to get the desired results. I tried disabling "snap windows to their original size", to then renable it and see if it worked. However, when I disabled it, the windows lost their title bars, the panel, dash and launcher were gone. I usually run "unity --replace" when this sort of thing happens, but because there was no dash I couldn't run any commands. So I pressed Ctrl+Alt+F6b (not sure what this is callled) and ran "unity --replace" from there. However unity wasn't restored and now I only have a top bar with only the appmenu and no launcher or dash. I tried to logout and reboot but neither worked. Gnome Shell works, though. Please help me, I don't want to reinstall the OS or something to solve this issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try running `unity --reset` from a terminal.

- [How do I reset my Unity configuration?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17610/how-do-i-reset-my-unity-configuration)

Answer (score 0):

If you delete the compiz config settings, they will be reset once you log in again. Try executing the following command, one-by-one:

```
rm -rf $HOME/.compiz-1  
rm -rf $HOME/.compiz/  
rm -rf $HOME/.config/compiz-1  
rm -rf $HOME/.gconf/apps/compiz-1  
rm -rf $HOME/.gconf/apps/compizconfig-1  
rm -rf $HOME/.cache/compizconfig-1
```

Comment: To avoid accidentally putting a space before or after the first slash, which *would delete all the files in your home directory including all your documents*, I'd suggest instead `cd`ing to `$HOME` and then doing `rm` on the relative paths: `cd; rm -rf .compiz-1 .compiz .config/compiz-1 .gconf/apps/compiz-1 .gconf/apps/compizconfig-1 .cache/compizconfig-1`